# Facebook pixel in Gatsby js/ React js

Tags: facebook, reactjs, google-analytics, gatsby

I've recently developed site using gatsbyjs and I want to use a facebook conversion pixel on the site(as well as Google analytics). I need ideas or help to make them work so I can run a conversion type ad. It would help tremendously if you spoke to me like a 5 year old.

The code that renders `<head>` is :

```js
module.exports = React.createClass({
  propTypes () {
    return {
      body: React.PropTypes.string,
    }
},

render () {
  const head = Helmet.rewind()
  let css
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  css = <style dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: require('!raw!./public/styles.css') }} />
    }

return (
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charSet="utf-8" />
      <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
      <meta
        name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
      />
      {head.title.toComponent()}
      {head.meta.toComponent()}
      <TypographyStyle typography={typography} />
      <GoogleFont typography={typography} />
      {css}
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="react-mount" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.body }} />
        <script src={prefixLink(`/bundle.js?t=${BUILD_TIME}`)} />
      </body>
    </html>
      )
    },
  })
```

and my facebook pixel looks like this:

```html
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', 'pixelID');
fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=pixelID&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- DO NOT MODIFY -->
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Answer (score 7):

React doesn't let you embed runnable code directly within `script` tags. Instead you need to use the odd sounding API `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. Your code should look something like:

```
<script
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `
    !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
    n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
    n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
    t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
    document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
    fbq('init', 'pixelID');
    fbq('track', 'PageView');
  `}}
/>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=pixelID&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
```

Add this code to the bottom of your html.js page and it should execute just fine.

Comment: There's not a lot of info about this out there, is this how other people are implementing 3rd party tracking code in a React SPA?

Comment: Yeah it's what I've seen.

Comment: I know this is old, by WHY is this being embedded as HTML at all? just put the function in file and import it on page load

Comment: Where exactly shall we do this in Gatsby?

Answer (score 6):

There is a Gatsby plugin available for Facebook Pixel here - https://github.com/gscopet/gatsby-plugin-facebook-pixel

It will take care of inserting the official Facebook Pixel JS by using the `onRenderBody` method of the Gatsby Server Rendering API and sending `ViewContent` events by using the `onRouteUpdate` method of the Gatsby Browser API.

It appears to have been modelled after the official Gatsby Google Analytics plugin which is available here - https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-plugin-google-analytics

Answer (score 3):

Remeber that on SPA's, the Analytics code needs to be refreshed every time you change a page. If you just run in on pageload, it won't track page changes.

At least in the Gatsby-template i'm using there is the needed code in `gatsby-browser.js`

```
import ReactGA from 'react-ga'
import { config, pages } from 'config'
import find from 'lodash/find'

if (config.gaCode) {
  ReactGA.initialize(config.gaCode)
}

exports.onRouteUpdate = state => {
  if (config.gaCode) {
    const page = find(pages, {path: state.pathname})
    ReactGA.ga('send', 'pageview', {
      location: location.pathname,
      title: page && page.data && page.data.title ? page.data.title : state.pathname,
      page: state.pathname
    })
  }
}
```

`exports.onRouteUpdate`is run every time a page is changed. Some discussion here:
https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/64

Comment: adding a quick comment - just implemented this method and it works, however the FB trackign pixel script wasnt being appended when in develop mode locally. after running the build process it was indeed there.

Answer (score 1):

First Gatsby doesn't Let you use script Like this so you should use:

```
   <script
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `
    !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
    n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
    n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
    t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
    document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
    fbq('init', 'pixelID');
    fbq('track', 'PageView');
  `}}
/></script>
```

Second: you can't you noscript you have to make it normal script Like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: `
    <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
      src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=678059259599817&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
    />`}}></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be obvious to some but make sure you turn off your adblocker for the site you are tracking. Otherwise, if it's a low traffic site and you are testing tracking on your machine, you won't see any activity.